# Rust struct field str slice with size

Tags: rust

I can do the following:

```
#[repr(C, packed)]
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
struct Test {
    field: [u8; 8],
}
```

But I want to format it as a string when I'm using the debug formatter, and I'm wondering if I could define the field as a str slice with a known size. I can't use String because I am loading the struct from memory, where it is not instantiated by my Rust program. I have read that string slices are represented using UTF-8 characters, but I need ASCII. Should I manually implement the `Debug` trait instead?

Comment: If the memory really is just an 8-byte section, consider using `#[repr(transparent)]` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no automatic way of doing that, so you'll have to manually implement `Debug`. Be careful, however, that not every `[u8; 8]` *is* valid UTF-8 (unless you're actually guaranteed to get ASCII).

To be safe, you could switch whether to print `field` as a string or as an array of bytes based on whether it's legal UTF-8:

```
use std::fmt;

impl fmt::Debug for Test {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        let utf8;
        let value: &dyn fmt::Debug = if let Ok(s) = std::str::from_utf8(&self.field) {
            utf8 = s;
            &utf8
        } else {
            &self.field
        };
        f.debug_struct("Test")
            .field("field", value)
            .finish()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let valid_ascii = Test {
        field: [b'a'; 8],
    };
    let invalid_ascii = Test {
        field: [0xFF; 8],
    };
    println!("{:?}", valid_ascii);   // Test { field: "aaaaaaaa" }
    println!("{:?}", invalid_ascii); // Test { field: [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255] }
}
```

If you're guaranteed valid ASCII, you can of course just use [`std::str::from_utf8_unchecked`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8_unchecked.html) and skip that step.

Comment: Depending on the strength of the guarantee, a perhaps better option is to use `str::from_utf8(...).unwrap()`, which will panic (instead of causing silent UB) if the guarantee is ever broken.

Comment: Since `Debug` is often not performance sensitive, [`String::from_utf8_lossy()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8_lossy) is also a good candidate.